# spring-boot is not creating hsqldb database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my current spring project, I start to use spring-boot with spring-jpa to create and manage a HSQLDb database.

I have this `hibernate.properties` in thee folder `src/main/resources` from my project:

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/home/kleber/.webapp/testedb
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.pass=

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

my pom.xml have this dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

my main class is that:

```
@Controller
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
    public String signin(Model model) {
        return "acesso/signin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
    public String admin(Model model) {
        return "private/admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "public/index";
    }

}
```

when I run the application, I can see this in the console:

```
2014-10-30 17:58:51.708  INFO 31413 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
2014-10-30 17:58:51.713  INFO 31413 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/home/kleber/.webapp/testedb, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect, hibernate.show_sql=false, jdbc.user=sa, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create, jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver, jdbc.pass=}
2014-10-30 17:58:51.714  INFO 31413 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2014-10-30 17:58:52.089  INFO 31413 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2014-10-30 17:58:52.191  INFO 31413 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
2014-10-30 17:58:52.385  INFO 31413 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-10-30 17:58:52.838  INFO 31413 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2014-10-30 17:58:52.845  INFO 31413 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

but no database is created in the path defined by the property `jdbc.url`.

ANyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you still trying to NOT use Spring Boot? You are just making things more difficult for yourself. That is the recurring theme in all the questions you asked. Work WITH the framework not around or against the framework.

Comment: How so? I am using spring-boot to manage the access to database. Do you see the code I posted here?

Comment: You are using hiberate.properties which is for hibernate and which is happily ignored by Spring Boot. You are manually configuring everything yourself. Spring Boot doesn't read the `hibernate.properties` hibernate is reading that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd be better using Spring Boot to manage your configuration. It will pass Hibernate configuration to Hibernate while also auto-creating your DataSource and database for you.

I would move all of your configuration into `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
# DataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/home/kleber/.webapp/testedb
spring.datasource.username=sa

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I've removed some unnecessary configuration. For example, the configuration of `driverClassName` as Spring Boot will infer it from the url and the empty DataSource password as that's the default. You can see some documentation of the configuration properties and their default values [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Comment: Why application.properties? When I run the application, the spring-boot looks for a file named hibernate.properties. Also, does really matters if I use all the options or no? my problem it's the database is not being created with this configuration (it's working when I manually configure it with a HibernateConfig class).

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't look for hibernate.properties, Hibernate does. You can see that from the log output you've included in the question. Putting the configuration in application.properties allows Spring Boot to configure things for you, reducing the amount of configuration that you have to do yourself. If you're not interested in having things configured automatically with sensible defaults and, instead, you prefer to configure everything manually, then you're missing out on one of the major reasons for using Spring Boot.

Comment: This thread is a little old, but still relevant. I added the url and username properties in order to get Spring to generate a file database and it still uses the in-memory. It creates the testdb... but it's not using it.

Comment: what is home is that linux based URL or root of executable?